# Python: use external function in "apply_async"

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-import

I'm starting to learn python and have to write a script which takes advantages of multiprocessing. It looks as follows:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)

import PoseOptimization2 as opt
import telemMS_Vicon as extr   
import Segmentation as seg

result_list = []
def log_result(result):
    # This is called whenever foo_pool(i) returns a result.
    # result_list is modified only by the main process, not the pool workers.
    result_list.append(result)
    print('Frame:',result[1])

def multiproc(seg):
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
    for i in range(0,len(seg)):
        pool.apply_async(opt.optimize, args=(seg[0],seg[i],False,False,i),callback=log_result)
     
    pool.close()
    pool.join()       
  

if __name__ == "__main__":   
          
    #extract point cloud data (list of arrays)
    OutputObj = extr.extraction('MyoSuit Custom Feasibility') 
    segments = seg.segmentation(OutputObj)
  
    multiproc(segments[0])      

   
    list1 = result_list
    result_list = []
```

In principle, the variable "segments" contains several lists. The entries of each list shall then be modified by using the function "optimize" in the "PoseOptimization2" script. To make this faster, I want to use multiprocessing.
But when I try to run the function "multiproc", there is the error "ModuleNotFoundErrorError: No module named PoseOptimization2" and the program has to be restarted in order to work again.

How can I properly pass a function from another script to the multiprocessing function?

Thank you very much for your help!